# Survey data : calibrate result according to number of response

Tags: survey

I ll do my best to explain the situation.
I'm trying to rank X supermarkets according to their performance.
I've done a survey with a set of Y clients and obtained an average grade for each supermarket.

The problem being is that for some supermarkets I got more answers than other supermarkets eg. supermarket 1 has 289 answers and supermarket 2 has 34 answers. Therefore the ranking is biased : supermarket 2 had less answers but has a better grade than supermarket 1, and supermarket 2 is ranked before supermarket 1 .

My question is do you know how to calibrate the data in order to get a grade which shows a better representation of the supermarket performance compared to the others ?

Thank you.

Comment: I would like to comment your question but I cannot because I do not have enough reputation yet. All depends from what is the criteria by which the grade was asked or not to reslibdents. Incidentally, I am assuming here that by consumer grade you mean a measure of liking of consumers vs the markets. If you you filtered at random, ie respondent were randomly selected to answer about market X or Y, you have random samples and theoretically your average should be OK. However a sample of 34 will have a high statistical error, thus producing a less reliable average. If you filtered by awareness or b

Comment: Why do you think having different numbers means the ranking is biased?

Comment: @Peter Characterizing this as a "bias" does not make the question unclear.

Answer (score 1):

More information about the survey and the difference in preferences
would be needed for a general answer to your question. However,
here is an example to use in your thinking about this discrepancy.

Consider one key summary question. "Overall, would you choose to shop
there again?" Suppose 189 out of 289 at market A said Yes and
26 out of 34 at market B said Yes. The proportions are 65% Yes for A
and 76% for B. But a test of proportions finds no significant difference.
Output from Minitab; P-value above 5%:

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample    X    N  Sample p
1       189  289  0.653979
2        26   34  0.764706

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.110727
95% CI for difference:  (-0.263492, 0.0420386)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  
  Z = -1.29  P-Value = 0.195
```

So it would be irresponsible to give B a higher rating than A.
Maybe an asterisk leading to a footnote, something like: 
"Too little data to rate.
Proportion of Yes's from a small number of responses is 76%.

*Note:* A major US consumer-oriented publication often prints numbered
lists of product or service rankings, along with a comment, such as: "Ratings must be separated
by about 5 positions on the list in order to be significantly different."